# How to only use input in pattern once?

Tags: regex, regex-group

regex = `^(movie|tv) (.*) (?<=season )([0-9 ]+)`

input = `tv game of thrones season 1 2 3`

output

```
tv
game of thrones season
1 2 3
```

desired output

```
tv
game of thrones
1 2 3
```

https://regex101.com/r/wG3aM3/954

`(.*)` captures all string before `([0-9 ]+)` how can i prevent it from capturing `(?<=season )` which is before `([0-9 ]+)`.

P.S i cant just negate "season" from `(.*)` . i.e `tv game of season season 1 2 3` should capture `tv` `game of season` `1 2 3`

Comment: `^(movie|tv) (.*) season ([0-9 ]+)`?

Comment: The issue is not related to pattern negation, you just want to omit part of a match. Is `season` always present in the strings?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no its optional it could be `movie inception` and still match

Comment: Sorry, `movie inception` is a possible input? So, the numbers at the end are optional?

Comment: yes.................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
^(movie|tv)\s*(.*?)(?:\s+season)?(?:\s+([0-9]+(?:\s+[0-9]+)*))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/icAsM6/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(movie|tv)` - Group 1: `movie` or `tv`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?:\s+season)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching one or more whitespaces followed with `season` string
- `(?:\s+([0-9]+(?:\s+[0-9]+)*))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching

  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `([0-9]+(?:\s+[0-9]+)*)` - Group 3: one or more digits followed with zero or more repetitions of one or more whitespace chars followed with one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks. This works although i modified it to this `^(movie|tv)\s*(.*?)(?:\s+season)?(?:(?<=season)\s+([0-9]+(?:\s+[0-9]+)*))?$`. I added a `(?<=season)` because group 3 should always follow `season` Also i dont quite understood why you used `([0-9]+(?:\s+[0-9]+)*)` over just `([0-9\s]+)`

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
^(movie|tv) (.*) (?:season )([0-9 ]+)
```

This just changes the lookahead (?<=season ) to a non-capturing group (?:season ). In python that would be:

```
import re
text = "tv game of thrones season 1 2 3"
output = re.findall(r"^(movie|tv) (.*) (?:season )([0-9 ]+)", text)
print(output)
#output: [('tv', 'game of thrones', '1 2 3')]
```

> A non-capturing version of regular parentheses. Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, but the substring matched by the group cannot be retrieved after performing a match or referenced later in the pattern.

see https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html